# Receiving the following error in my code "Invalid left-hand side in assignment"

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-platform

I am working on a sample code to test my webhook, but it is giving me this error.

Here is my code

```js
exports.random-project = function random-project(req, res) {
  response = “This is a sample response from your webhook!”; //Default response from the webhook to show it's working

res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json'); //Requires application/json MIME type
  res.send(JSON.stringify({ "speech": response, "displayText": response 
  //"speech" is the spoken version of the response, "displayText" is the visual version
  }));
};
```

Comment: You also have illegal quotes around the string `response = “This is a sample response from your webhook!”`  Those look like they come from a word processor that has left and right double quotes.  You can't use those.  Only normal single or double quote.  Never ever use a word processor for code.  Only  use an actual plain text or code editor.

Answer (score 3):

You can't include a dash in a key name unless you use quotes... it is better to camel-case the variable

```
exports["random-project"] = function () { ... }
```

or

```
exports.randomProject = function () { ... }
```